# Using Genius MousePen i608 with multiple screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-tablet

I own Genius MousePen i608, and I want to use it with multiple screens (just on one screen), but the tablet is controling every screen, so the area on it is splitted in half (first half for first monitor, second for the other one). I want to use it only on one monitor (the external one). I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually *exactly* the reason I created my xrestrict utility. Here is its [github page](https://github.com/Ademan/xrestrict/). Look at the **Building** section to see how to build it, I'd also be happy to walk you through setup and basic usage if you're not familiar with building software from source on Ubuntu. I also wrote a [blog post](https://ademan.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/inexpensive-monoprice-tablet/) describing the utility in a bit more detail, and illustrating what it does. In short, once you build it, just run `xrestrict -I` and click on the monitor you want to use using your tablet stylus.

Comment: Thank you, but when I click on the monitor (1st or 2nd) it will say that it Failed to find absolute X and Y valuators for device 12.

Comment: My bad, I figured out how to do it, instead of xrestrict -I I have to use xrestrict -d DEVID -c 0

Comment: Both *should* work. When you clicked on the monitor, were you using your tablet stylus? (It will fail with that message if you use your mouse, for instance) If it failed when you were using your tablet stylus then that's a bug, and I'll take a look into fixing it. Thanks for trying out the utility! I hope it's easy enough and useful enough to be worth your time.

Comment: I used mouse :) Please write that into documentation if it is not there already :)

Comment: Thanks! I actually haven't even updated the github docs for -I, and I didn't mention it here either, sorry about that! I'm going to edit it into my original reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a graphical tool in development that might work for you.  No compilation because Python, but may need to install a few packages... xinput, xrandr, python-gtk2 and python-appindicator.  Check it out here:
http://wenhsinjen.github.io/ptxconf/